# Change prototype of a prototype to affect instance JS

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an instance of a class, but I don't have access to that instance, only to the class itself. Can I modify the prototype of the class so that the instance receives an update to its methods also?

```
class B { c() { console.log('B') } }
class C { c() { console.log('C') } }
const b = new B // newbie :P
// now no access to b
// I want:
B.prototype.__proto__ = C.prototype
// now yes access to b
b.c() // prints C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close: You can replace the method through `B`'s `prototype`:

```js
class B { c() { console.log('B') ;} }
const b = new B();

B.prototype.c = () => { console.log("C"); }
b.c() // prints C
```

You *can't* just replace the whole prototype, you'd really need to change the properties on the prototype:

```js
class B { c() { console.log('B') ;} }
class C { c() { console.log('C') ;} }
const b = new B();

B.prototype = C.prototype;
b.c() // This still prints `B`
```

Comment: alright man, so I'd have to manually iterate through all properties, no way to do it in one go, also making sure that those methods that no longer exist are gone?

Comment: Yea, you need to replace the properties on the prototype, which would involve some manual manipulation.

Comment: k cool i'll accept this later on if no one else suggests anything else :+1: thx

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you might have some use for [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). Then all you need to worry about is deleting methods that no longer exist.

Comment: any thoughts on how to update bounded function of an instance? e.g., i bound c in the constructor like this.c = this.c.bind(this), and obviously after updating of the prototype it won't work... thoughts? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that, no, @zavr.

Comment: just so you know, I had to use `Object.defineProperties(A.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(B.prototype))` because when you access a getter, it gets executed instead of returning the method :P